# Use Verbatim tag inside a django simple tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates, handlebars.js

I wrote a simple tag that gets one argument and returns True or False.

```
@register.simple_tag
def iswatched(movieDB_id):
    try:
        movie = TitleMovie.objects.get(movieDB_id=movieDB_id)
        return movie.watched
    except:
        return False
```

I use a javaScript library called Handlebars which has syntax exactly like Django template tag.
So I use {%verbatim%} tag to not render those parts.
but I need to get the value with Handlebars tag like this ( `{{value}}` ) and pass it to simple tag `{%iswatched {{value}} as watched%}`.
but it gets an error because it render `{{value}}` as Django template tag.

I tried this but it didn't work.
`{%iswatched ({%verbatim%}{{id}}{%endverbatim%}) as watched%}`.

how should i have it not render `{{value}}` inside `iswatched` simple tag

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want your client-side Handlebars template to execute _before_ your server-side Django template so that you can pass the `{{value}}` value to the `iswatched` helper. If this is correct, it is not achievable because the Django code - being server-side - executes long before the Handlebars code. What do you expect the value of `{{value}}` to be?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need, execute the client-side Handlebars template before Django starts rendering the page.
the value of `{{value}}` is the ID of movies that I get from an API.
I get it from an XMLrequest and handle it with handlebars

Comment: It is not possible to execute the Handlebars before the Django. The Django produces the HTTP response which the browser converts into a document and then executes the JavaScript, including the Handlebars. Could this `iswatched` tag be written as a Handlebars helper? It seems to me that the `movie` objects which get fed to your Handlebars template probably already have the `watched` property; and if not, it shouldn't be difficult to add it to them.

Comment: Yes it seems like I can't execute the JavaScript before django start rendering the page. I've come up with a new idea to solve this. I'm gonna try django rest api and fetch data with a handlebar helper form the api. It might solve this problem. (And `movie` object which get fed to handlebar template doesn't have a watched property, it's an object from an api. But module `TitleMovie` which i wrote does have)